# Kotlin: FragmentManager is showing error when called from Fragment [working with Adapter]

Tags: android, kotlin

AdapterClass:

```
class TeamsAdapter(
supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager,
teams_list: MutableList<Team>,
match_id: String
) : FragmentPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {code}
```

Fragment Class:

```
lateinit var teamsAdapter: TeamsAdapter

teamsAdapter = TeamsAdapter(supportFragmentManager, match?.teams!!, matchId)
```

Error: `Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager`

But the entire code works fine when inside an Activity instead of Fragment Class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by casting activity if you are using fragment then cast with context

```
  fragmentManager = (activity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
```

Comment: Using the Activity's fragment manager for a ViewPager hosted within a Fragment is **always** the wrong thing to do. You should use the `childFragmentManager` for nesting fragments.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **parentFragmentManager** or **childFragmentManager** for using fragment manager inside of a fragment. There is no need to use any sort of casting for using a fragment manager.

```
parentFragmentManager or getParentFragmentManager()
```

> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment's activity.  Note that this will available slightly before {@link #getActivity()}, during the time from when the fragment is placed in a {@link FragmentTransaction} until it is committed and attached to its activity.If this Fragment is a child of another Fragment, the FragmentManager returned here will be the parent's {@link #getChildFragmentManager()}. @throws IllegalStateException if not associated with a transaction or host.

```
childFragmentManager or getChildFragmentManager()
```

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

I just read that you are learning something new, so I suggest it is better to use the best practices. Casting sometimes generates errors and crashes, so I suggest you use these.

Comment: That seems ok as far as IDE allows however when compiling all I receive is "Unresolved reference: parentFragmentManager". I went back to using activity.supportFragmentManager in my fragments.

Answer (score 1):

When your fragment contains a ViewPager that uses fragments, you must always use the `childFragmentManager` for that ViewPager as that's what allows FragmentManager to properly nest those fragments and ensure that their state is properly saved and restored.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `supportFragmentManager` if you are supporting device below API 14, otherwise just use `fragmentManager`

Comment: Current implementation of `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` is based on support library ([android.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) was deprecated). So, you cannot use `fragmentManager`, only `supportFragmentManager `. Also [fragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/FragmentManager) was deprecated.